# Display number of variants as a value

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is it possible to display the number of variants a product has?

This would be in order to achieve the following:

> This product is available in **3** colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already got the product (which is a [ProductModel](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/product-model#variants)) in Twig, it's a simple as:

```
This product is available in {{ product.variants|length }} colors.
```